# How to write Scrollable for Table in j2me by canvas?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

Now i try to draw a table by Canvas, but i have a problem, my table doesnt has scrollable.

How can i write some code to help my table can scrollable?

My Code here

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Graphics;

/**
 *
 * @author Kency
 */
public class TableCanvas extends Canvas{

    private int w,h;
    private int pad;
    private int cols = 3;
    private int rows = 10;

    public TableCanvas() {
        w = getWidth();
        h = getHeight();


    }




    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(148, 178, 255);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        for(int i =0 ; i <= cols ; i++){
            g.setColor(0x00D0D0D0);

            for(int j = 0 ; j <= rows ; j++){
                g.drawLine(0, j *  h/rows, cols * w, j* h/rows);
                g.drawLine(i * w/cols, 0, i * w/cols, w * rows);
            }
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For code like in your excerpt, most straightforward way would probably be with [Graphics#translate](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#translate%28int,%20int%29) API.

One would also have to handle key pressed / pointer events to allow user to scroll. Eg when key press corresponds to game action right/left/up/down, you scroll respectively. When pointer is dragged, you find out the direction and, again, scroll respectively

Painting scrollbar(s) would also require "handmade" code.

Another option would be using 3rd party library like *LWUIT* or *J2ME Polish*

Comment: Dear gnat

Can you give me some ideas about key press or pointer events to handle scroll?

Thank you!

Comment: @MYE I added explanation to my answer "when key press corresponds to game action right/left/up/down, you scrol..." etc